# Mongo Aggregate return without array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database query which joins two tables and returns the result as an array, but I can't be more than one element and the array I don't need:

```
Model.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'translations',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'item_id',
        as: 'translation'
    },
}, 
{
    $project: {
        "label": 1, 
        "items": 1,
        "translation": {

        }
    }
}], function(err, data) {
    callback(err, data);
})
```

And my result:

```
[ { _id: 58b95bad4321200de3f61a31,
label: 'BLUECHIPS',
items: [],
translation: [] } ]
```

I want result without array, for example:

```
{ _id: 58b95bad4321200de3f61a31,
label: 'BLUECHIPS',
items: [],
translation: [] }
```

How do that?

Comment: Have you tried just returning the data as `callback(err, data[0]);`?

Comment: I know)))) but my question how receive result without array?

Comment: You use return the first element like the above commenters propose.  You can't change what the library is returning, but you can map it however you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new static method to your model that does what you need.

```
Model.statics.aggregateOne = function aggregateOne(array, cb) {
  this.aggregate(array, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(data[0]);
  });
}
```

which you should now be able to use as:

```
Model.aggregateOne([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'translations',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'item_id',
        as: 'translation'
    },
}, 
{
    $project: {
        "label": 1, 
        "items": 1,
        "translation": {

        }
    }
}], function(err, data) {
    callback(err, data);
});
```

which is the same code as you posted, just with a different method name.